# Conditions under which all the eigenvalues of any $n \times n$ matrix are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to know conditions under which all the eigenvalues of any $n \times n$ matrix are equal. For $n=2$ it is easy to find such condition. 
Thanks

Comment: There are lots of possible characterizations---can you be more specific about what you have in mind? What is your characterization for $n = 2$?

Comment: One possible characterization of such matrices $A$ is the existence of some $\lambda$ such that $A - \lambda I$ is nilpotent, that is, that $(A - \lambda I)^m = 0$ for some positive integer $m$ ($m = n$ always suffices but in general is not minimal).

Comment: How is $(n A - \operatorname{Trace}(A) \cdot I_n)^n = 0$ ?

Comment: @orangeskid This is probably outside the scope OP originally intended, but that condition appears to be necessary but not sufficient over fields of finite characteristic. For example, consider $n = 3$ and $A = \pmatrix{0&&\\&1&\\&&2}$ over $\Bbb F_3$.

Comment: @Travis: Yes, I like this example. But your condition still holds. With the caveat (maybe overdoing it) that the $\lambda$ might be in a field extension.

Comment: @Travis: for $n=2$, $a_{11}=a, a_{12}=b, a_{21}=0, a_{22}=a$ where $a_{ij}$ is $(i,j)$-th entry of matrix.

Comment: @applied_math Yes, and in fact we can allowed $a_{21}$ to be arbitrary too.

Answer (score 0):

In general one can produce a system of $n - 1$ polynomials in the entries of an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ (of degrees $2 n - 2, 2 n - 4, \ldots, 2$) that vanish iff all of the eigenvalues of $A$ coincide. For algebro-geometric reasons for all $n$ this is the minimal number of polynomials that can realize such a condition (over an algebraically complete field, anyway).

Recall that the eigenvalues of the roots of an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial $$p_A(t) := \det(t I - A) .$$
Therefore, its eigenvalues of $A$ all coincide iff $p_A$ has a root of order $n$.

Now, a polynomial $p_A$ has a multiple root iff its discriminant $\Delta(p_A)$ vanishes---recall that the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) is a homogeneous polynomial (in this case, of degree $2 n - 2$) in the entries of $A$. So, $n = 2$ this already gives a sufficient and necessary polynomial condition. Since
$$p_A(t) = t^2 - (\operatorname{tr} A) t + \det A,$$
and so the two eigenvalues of $A = \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$ coincide iff
$$\Delta(p_A) = (\operatorname{tr} A)^2 - 4 \det A = a^2 - 2 a d + d^2 + 4 b c$$
is zero.

For $n > 2$ the vanishing of $\Delta(p_A)$ is a necessary but not sufficient condition, as some but not all eigenvalues may coincide. On the other hand, a monic polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ has a root of order $n$ iff the discriminants of the derivatives of $p$ up to the $(n - 2)$nd all vanish. So: A necessary and sufficient condition for all the eigenvalues of $A$ to coincide is the vanishing of the discriminants
$$\color{#df0000}{\boxed{\Delta(p_A), \Delta(p_A'), \ldots, \Delta(p_A^{(n - 2)})}} .$$

For $n = 3$, we may write the characteristic polynomial as
$$t^3 - (\operatorname{tr} A) t^2 + \sigma_2(A) t - \det A,$$
where $\sigma_2(A)$ is the quadratic elementary symmetric polynomial in the eigenvalues of $A$, which in terms of the entries $a_{ij}$ of $A$ is
$$\sigma_2(A) = a_{11} a_{22} + a_{11} a_{33} - a_{12} a_{21} - a_{13} a_{31} + a_{22} a_{33} - a_{23}a_{32}.$$
Then, the [usual formula for the discriminant of a cubic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_3) gives the conditions
\begin{align}
\Delta(p_A)  &= (\operatorname{tr} A)^2 \sigma_2(A)^2 - 4 \sigma_2(A) - 4 (\operatorname{tr} A)^3 \det A - 27 (\det A)^2 + 18 \operatorname{tr} A \,\sigma_2(A) \det A \\
\Delta(p_A') &= 4 [(\operatorname{tr} A)^2 - 3 \sigma_2(A)] .
\end{align}

If you want to produce explicit formulas directly in terms of the entries, then for $n > 2$ you might prefer to expand orangeskid's condition from the comments, namely,
$$(n A - (\operatorname{tr} A) I)^n = 0,$$
which is a polynomial system of $n^2$ equations of degree $n$ in the entries of $A$. (NB, as hinted in the comments, this condition is necessary but not sufficient over a field of prime characteristic dividing $n$.) Even for $n = 3$ these latter conditions look more manageable.